# Can't extract mp3 audio from video with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

My input is a .mp4 video file.

Try #1

```
ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -y -map a media/73.mp3
```

Error:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f977d800000] stream 1, offset 0xa8: partial file
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f977d800000] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 320x176, 300 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pipe:0':
  Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
creation_time   : 2012-03-13T08:58:06.000000Z
encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.6 2012022800
  Duration: 00:00:10.03, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 320x176, 300 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2012-03-13T08:58:06.000000Z
  encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2012-03-13T08:58:06.000000Z
Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2012-03-13T08:58:06.000000Z
Stream #0:3(und): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2012-03-13T08:58:06.000000Z
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f977d800000] stream 1, offset 0xa8: partial file
pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
Finishing stream 0:0 without any data written to it.
Finishing stream 0:1 without any data written to it.
[mp3 @ 0x7f977b846800] Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- 
Conversion failed!
```

---

Try #2

```
ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -y -vn -acodec copy media/72.mp3
```

Error:

```
[...]
[mp3 @ 0x7febed835200] Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

---

Try #3

```
ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -y -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 media/74.mp3
```

No error with `ffmpeg`, but the file is invalid (it's size is 334 bytes)

---

Try #4

```
ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -y -vn -acodec mp3 media/78.mp3
```

No error with `ffmpeg`, but the file is invalid (it's size is 334 bytes)

---

Try #5

```
ffmpeg -f mp4 -i pipe:0 -y media/80.mp3
```

No error with `ffmpeg`, but the file is invalid (it's size is 334 bytes)

---

What am I doing wrong? This seems like a fairly easy thing to do...

Comment: Why are you trying to pipe the MP4 file instead of using it like a normal input? `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp3`

Comment: I'm using `node-fluent-ffmpeg` and I thought it necessitated a `ReadStream`. You're right, pointing directly to the input file path works as expected. I wonder why piping the video isn't working, I have no problem converting audio files (e.g. wav to mp3) when piping. Furthermore, we can see that the video is a valid input in the first error message I posted. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Typical MP4 files are not pipe friendly.

Comment: Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FFmpeg can't update metadata in WAVE files when output is written over a non-seekable protocol like a pipe. Quicktime seems to rely on metadata to determine file validity. You have to write to file or some other seekable protocol.

Please refer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1436830/how-to-convert-raw-pcm-data-to-a-valid-wav-file-with-ffmpeg).

Answer (score 10):

Try this for extract `.mp3`:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -map 0:a -acodec libmp3lame out.mp3
```

And maybe this useful for extract `.m4a`:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -map 0:a -c copy out.m4a
```

Answer (score 1):

All is said by  `backendscript`  in  http://www.backendscript.com/blog/article/solved-ffmpeg-invalid-audio-stream-exactly-one-mp3-audio-stream-is-required

> An aac audio stream requires a dedicated aac container ! As a mp3 udio
>   stream requires a dedicated mp3 container ! This error occurs when we
>   trying to store an AAC stream in an MP3 container. To resolve this
>   change the extension of output file from .mp3 to .aac

Generate error Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -acodec copy output.mp3
```

Working fine

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -acodec copy output.aac
```